# Some open file dialogs don't see other partitions

Tags: hard-drive, filemanager, dialog, places

I tried to get some photos from my second internal HDD (native SATA at Chipset) to [Wallch](http://melloristudio.com/wallch/). But I don't see any of my internal and external HDDs in the open dialog's left pane (Places), except for the partition with Ubuntu (see image below). I can see the hard drives in Unity Launcher, but not in the open file dialog.

I experienced the same with [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) and [Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/), so I think it is an Ubuntu problem. Normally I can use the HDDs well and I didn't experience any problems.

[image]

Ubuntu 15.10/Clevo P771DM/i5-6600K/Intel Z170/970M

Comment: If you already have `gparted` installed, you could use it to see what partitions and devices it sees and how they are formatted. 

It's a place to start, anyway.

Comment: What are we supposed to see in the image? Asian dude stretching? Also, I am unsure what Wallch, OBS and Variety are.

Comment: Please include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and highlight the device(s) in question. If they don't show up, look through the output of `sudo dmesg` for hints and include them in your question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a QT file/folder dialog which doesn't show (un)mounted drives in the left column. This happens because the developer(s) of those applications didn't add places and URLs to the dialog sidebar using [QFileDialog::setSidebarUrls()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setSidebarUrls).

Yet, you can still access mounted drives:

1. Plug in the HDD and click on it in the file manager to get it mounted.
2. In that file dialog, navigate to `/media/<username>` or `/mnt` folders and you should see the hard drive partitions as folders there. You can browse in them the contents of the drives.

You must navigate to the mount point of the partition. There you'll find its contents. You can see mount points in Disks utility (`gnome-disks`).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To view all available partitions you can try and use the lsblk command.

Open your terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd> then type:

```
sudo lsblk
```

this will give you a list of all the drives / partitions available on the system.
Once you know the device you can mount it using the:

```
sudo mount
```

command.